# Why was this question reopened?

Tags: discussion

This question was closed by vote as being trivia and therefore off topic: [Is this the biggest age gap between romantic leads where the actress is the older?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/117657/is-this-the-biggest-age-gap-between-romantic-leads-where-the-actress-is-the-olde)

Then, it seems after an edit that as far as I can tell changed nothing about the essential nature of the question, it was reopened by a mod.

How is this question not trivia?

Comment: ... maybe things have changed but this sort of question wasn't why the trivia close reason exists... it's specifically for questions that can be easily answered by IMDb - such as who wrote/performed/directed/composed etc.... a film. I don't think it's simple to get the answer to this specific question in that way.

Comment: @Catija seems like an answer I would accept. Although “answerable by IMDb” leaves some room for interpretation. This question could potentially be answered with IMDb if a person were thorough enough.

Comment: In https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic trivia is defined as "Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title", not as "can be answered by using IMDb". I don't see how the age difference is relevant, other than this being a rare case where the female character is significantly older. If the age difference isn't a factor in the movie, why would it be relevant?

Comment: @BCdotWEB I often end up uncomfortable with definitions like that because they're somewhat subjective and sometimes it's difficult to ascertain what's going to follow that guideline. For example, how many times someone says an expletive in a movie might immediately seem like trivia but if it's about the South Park Movie and the explanation includes that they had to stop at that exact number or be rated X.... it's more important and does add to the appreciation.

Comment: @Catija Of course all close reasons are at least a little bit subjective. That’s why there are votes to close and reopen and discussions in meta. In this case I’m a bit frustrated that five users voted to close and then one mod just reopened it summarily. It doesn’t seem to me to be appropriate use of mod powers.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Moderators are exception handlers, for example when the community is about to close a question that is already in the process of getting improved due to close-votes which mostly arrived before it was edited. (Or when it generally starts to get out of hand in its somewhat overzealous application of the "trivia" close-vote.)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson To me the edit helped not at all. In fact the lack of improvement from the edit for me just confirms that it’s trivia. To me, a lot of VTCs require subjective judgement by community members, and in this case it feels like one persons interpretation has overridden several others who agree. And maybe it was taken for granted that close voters hadn’t seen the edit, which is not true in my case. In short, why do diamond mods assume their interpretation is better than others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was on the verge of getting closed for being trivia. Then the asker added additional explanations as to why the matter is relavant as requested in the comments. So I reopened it, as the close-reason didn't really seem to apply anymore. That's exactly how the trivia close reason is supposed to work. It's about motivating the relevance of your ostensibly banal question in order to show why the internet ought to care, which the asker did.

As Catija explains, this close-reason is for guiding us against useless IMDb bar talk, not for shutting off questions whose relevance to the film *or* the film industry at large can be shown by the asker. It's a hoop to jump through when your question looks like banal trivia, which the asker did for the pleasure of the community.

Comment: That does answer my question, I suppose. I just find the explanation added in the edit seems a bit inauthentic. Like “isn’t this trivia?” “No, it’s important”. “Oh, ok then”. And I guess what seems relevant to you still seems like useless trivia to me.